# Unsure how to talk to management

Tags: management, lying

Recently in one-on-ones, I've been asked "which types of projects would you like to work on?". I've given my answer. Sometimes I'm even given the choice between two options.

Each time I'm given a choice, or a project opens up, I get whatever I said I would not prefer.

At this point I'm used to it. I understand our constraints, and how important I may or may not be to the company. I provide value by wearing many hats. That's fine.

**My question: what should I say in one-on-ones?** It feels awkward to keep having the same conversation.. and I'm not sure how to fake happiness about something I've told them I'm not interested in. I'm interested in keeping my job and doing my best.

At this point, sure, I'd like to work on X, Y, and Z.. but I hold no illusions about management keeping its word or remotely caring about training or career development (a different, but very similar story). At this point, I'm happy to be employed, and am working on personal development outside of work.

Comment: What are the reasons you keep getting the less preferred projects? Is it that everybody wants to work on project A, and it's just bad luck that you keep drawing the short straw? Or are your colleagues more senior, more qualified,or just get along better with management? Or maybe it's the other way around and you keep getting assigned to projects you don't want because you've got the most experience with that kind of project. In your 1:1 you should try to address these underlying issues.

Comment: I think it's a mixture of things. We're a small company, so they want us to be billing hours as much as possible, there are more senior people than me, and I have a broader set of skills than most (they were known as an X company (where X = an area of tech), but now they're branching out more.

Answer (score 7):

**You should ask about why you are not getting the options you prefer.**

The fact that you are being asked your opinion is good, and the fact that you aren't getting the option you choose doesn't mean management is out to get to.

One probable scenario is that everybody is being asked their choice. However if the difference is between Project A with cool new in-demand technology, and Project B which is legacy maintenance using old technology, everybody has chosen Project A. Who gets Project A then comes down to those who are best qualified. There may be other factors such as seniority, how long they have been with the company etc.

So ask about the reason. It may be something like that. Point out that you've gotten your non-preferred choice several times. Suggest that if it is down to who is skilled in certain technologies, adding to the number of people who knows them is going to help the company.

Don't fake happiness. That's the wrong way to go. If you send the message "I'm happy with not getting my non-preferred option all the time" then they will keep giving you your non-preferred option, given preference to the people who aren't happy. Instead express your disappointment, coupled with a willingness to put aside your disappointment for now and do whatever is best for the company. Suggest that maybe they could give you your preferred option at least one time, and that will make working on second-choice projects easier to bear.

Comment: I've expressed this. I'm confused as to why they keep asking, where they sometimes tell me I'll be working on a preferred project, and then change it up last minute. They're very polite, but at a certain point it feels like lying, or treating me like a child. I'm not sure if there's anything I can do about that though.

Comment: And the crux of my answer is: ask them why this is happening.